# Does Jensen's Inequality hold for complex numbers?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, jensen-inequality

We can use Jensen's inequality to show that if $1<p<\infty$, then there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:
$$
|x+y|^p \leq C (|x|^p + |y|^p)
$$
Can we show this inequality for complex numbers? If so, can we use Jensen's inequality to show it? According to wikipedia, the usual definition of convexity is only for *real* vector spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For complex numbers $z, w$
$$
 |z+w|^p \le (|z| + |w|)^p \, .
$$
Now apply your inequality to the real numbers $x = |z|$ and
$y = |w|$:
$$
(|z| + |w|)^p \le C (|z|^p + |w|^p) \, .
$$

Comment: Of course; it's obvious once you see. Thanks!